# Conditional Probability given unlimited information?

Tags: probability

We know that $P(A|B)$ is more accurate than $P(A)$ because we taken into account the information $B$. My question is if we know all the information contributing to "$A$ occurs" then should P(A|those information) be 0 or 1?

Example: Considering the experiment of tossing a coin, and $A$ is the event that we have Head.  If we know all the information about the movement of the coin, how it lands, what is the surface it lands on, etc.  Then we should be able to calculate exactly $A$ occurs or not, right?

Comment: Probability theory is basically agnostic about these kinds of questions. Indeed one of the triumphs of measure-theoretic probability is that it *can* be agnostic about these kinds of questions while still furnishing the results that we want.

Comment: Yes. Formally this means $E(1_A|\sigma(A))=1_A\in \{0,1\}$.

Comment: The problem is that you never know all the information that determines $A$. There are "unknown unknowns" that you simply can't model and there is a minuscule, but positive, chance that the world will come to an end before the coin lands or that a coin will disintegrate in the air.

Answer (score 1):

The question can be interpreted mathematically or physically, as evidenced by A.S.'s two quite different comments.

The answer to the question as interpreted mathematically is given formally in A.S.'s first comment; more informally, we could say that "all the information contributing to '$A$ occurs'" includes whether $A$ occurs, so it gives us full knowledge of whether $A$ occurs.

My answer to the question as interpreted physically would be that on a practical level we never have full information, as this would include e.g. butterflies in Brazil, and on a philosophical level it's not clear whether this concept of full information makes sense or involves a confusion between reality and our models of reality.